# iOS app posting to Facebook using ShareKit, why need Privacy Policy?

Tags: ios, facebook, app-store, privacy-policy

My app was rejected because I did not have a Privacy Policy:
"Apps that include account registration or access a user’s existing account must include a privacy policy or they will be rejected".

I saw related question here:
[Apple store rejected iOS application due to background modes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26032995/apple-store-rejected-ios-application-due-to-background-modes)
but not quite the same as my question, so I create a new one.

My app uses ShareKit to connect to Facebook, Youtube, and configured for using OAuth 2.0.
Is there anyway for my app to access to user data like username or password? I think not.

I understand that from my view (developer), my app cannot access those user data.
But from user's perspective, they only see that my app request them to enter their credential.

**So what kind of contents my Privacy Policy should have?**
(I have apps that also use ShareKit to post to Facebook before, but this time they rejected).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: This isn't really a programming-related question, and might not be particularly suitable for StackExchange.

Your Privacy Policy should, basically, outline what you do with the information provided. Detailing information you collect and don't collect. You don't collect much? That's great! But you should still explain what the information you do collect is used for - even if it's not much.

I also personally make a point of telling my users what kinds of things I don't collect to give them some piece of mind. I doubt Apple would require you to go into too much detail on this, but as a user I would get some piece of mind if (for example) an app specifically says they *don't* use my email address to send spam or sell it to 3rd parties.